# Having trouble with ASP.NET Core role based authorisation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Role based authorisation isn't working in ASP.NET Core app. Any ideas?

Comment: can you elaborate on what is not working? What error are you facing in particular? What is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using HTTPS? If it is turned off from the Project properties, try to enable it and then try again.

Comment: That did the trick. I didn't realize that it was turned off. Appreciate the answer. Saved the day.